# Jmter stays in Tidying up state end of run and it takes around 2 hours to generated the HTML report for a large volume of results

Tags: jmeter

Using below command I ran a Jmter plan per 2 hours in Centos 7 environment.

```
nohup  jmeter -n -t HTTP_BasicPlan.jmx -l GrafanaTestSummaryreport.csv -j mylog.log -e -o TestResultReportFolder > myprogram.out & 2>&1
```

At the end of the exaction . TO generate  the HTML report,  it takes another 2 hours and then generates the HTML report.

summary = 177532912 in 02:15:14 = 21878.8/s Avg:     5 Min:     0 Max: 933392 Err:    13 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Thu Oct 07 08:33:22 UTC 2021 (1633595602066)
... end of run

Anyway to speed up the report generation? Thank you.

Comment: What's the size of the test result file?

Comment: It's a 15 GB file.

Comment: Are you saving the response data? Please save only the required fields.